# How to get a subscript into an axis title in `ggplot`

Tags: r, ggplot2, superscript

I want to have -1 in an axis title with the -1 being superscript. The title on my `y` axis should read `"Ba:Ca (µmol:mol-1)"` with the -1 as superscript. I have tried `^` before the -1 and also the expression function to no avail. `R` Rookie, please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this something you want?

```
set.seed(4)
x <- runif(20, 5, 10)
y <- runif(20, 15, 20)

df <- data.frame(x,y)

ggplot()+
  geom_point(data=df, aes(x,y))+
  labs(y = expression(paste('Ba:Ca (µmol:mol'^-1,')')), x = "x axis")
```

[image: Output]

Comment: This link to [mathematical annotation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html) might help

Comment: That's perfect except I need a space between the mol and -1 i.e. mol -1 rather than mol-1 (on top of each other).

Comment: All good, I edited it with ~ and it worked:                                                  + labs(y= expression (paste('Ba:Ca (µmol mol'^~-1,')')),

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively we could use `bquote`

```
ggplot()+
    geom_point(data=mtcars, aes(cyl,mpg))+
    labs(y = bquote('Ba:Ca'~(µmol<.mol^-1)))
```

[image]